# How do I make every plane in ContourPlot3D look like a perfect rectangle?

Tags: plotting

When a plane in `ContourPlot3D` hits the boundary of you plot range it will be naturally cut of there. This will not always give pretty pictures.

For example here I get an irregular hexagon (what I don't want)

```
ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 
   1}, {x3, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot I don't want]

here I get a rectangle (what I want)

```
ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - .1 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 
  1}, {x3, -1, 1}]
```

[image: plot I want]

How do I always get pretty rectangles even if my plane is oriented such that it hits the boundary of you plot range region in funny looking places?

Ideally, I would like to have an very easy option in `ContourPlot3D`, which does this automatically, since I will be doing lots of linear algebra plots which have solutions as intersecting planes. I would like to use `ContourPlot`, since this allows me to type in equations.

I have the latest Mathematica version and this will be used in an official publication and in my YouTube channel.

***** edit *****

I'm working in an affine space, where I want to invoke different inner products later on. So I do NOT like to use any normal vectors or anything that assumes perpendicularity, length, angle or an inner product. In that way I can really authentically communicate mathematics through Mathematica.

Comment: It happens even if you use primitives precisely due to clipping: `Graphics3D[Hyperplane[{1, 2, -2}, 0], PlotRange -> 1]` So, you're looking for a plot range where the plane looks rectangular?

Comment: So your'e not looking to draw a plane, but rather a rectangle? You can use Graphics3D[Polygon[...]] and calculate 4 points on your plane that form the edges of your rectangle.

Comment: I do not like to draw a rectangle, I would like to check a mathematical equation. To see if points lie on a plane, or planes meet in a point. So it is about displaying linear equations. Now these equations I would like to look like pretty planes, if possible.

Comment: @ennui, I want that the planes look like pretty planes in a given plot range. So I'm not looking for a plot range. I would like mathematica to truncate the plane earlier to get the largest rectangle possible in that plot range for example (Although a smaller one, or scalable rectangle is fine too).

Comment: "pretty" is subjective, so you'd need to somehow make a concrete criterion out of "pretty".

Comment: Perfect rectangular is what I'm looking for. But I want to use the expression of an equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent clipping at the top and bottom:

**1.** You can set the `x3` range to cover the minimum and maximum values of `x3` under the constraints given by the first argument and the ranges of `x1` and `x2`:

```
{zmin, zmax} = Through[{NMinValue, NMaxValue}[{x3, 
  x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0 && -1 <= x1 <= 1 && -1 <= x2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]]
```

> ```
> {-1.5, 1.5}
> ```

```
ContourPlot3D[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0}, {x1, -1, 1}, {x2, -1, 1}, {x3, zmin, zmax}]
```

[image]

**2.** You can also use [`ImplicitRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImplicitRegion.html) or [`ParametricRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricRegion.html):

```
impreg = ImplicitRegion[{x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0 && -1 <= x1 <= 1 && -1 <= x2 <= 1},
  {x1, x2, x3}]
```

> ```
> ImplicitRegion[x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0 && -1 <= x1 <= 1 && -1 <= x2 <= 1,  
>  {x1, x2, x3}]
> ```

You can use `impreg` with `RegionPlot3D`:

```
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[impreg], Mesh -> Automatic, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `CoordinateBounds @ impreg` to get the variable limits and use them with `ContourPlot3D`:

```
vlims = Sequence @@ MapThread[Prepend[#]@#2 &] @
   {{x1, x2, x3}, CoordinateBounds @ impreg};

ContourPlot3D[x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0, Evaluate[vlims], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
parreg = ParametricRegion[{{x1, x2, x3}, 
  x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0 && -1 <= x1 <= 1 && -1 <= x2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]

RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[parreg], Mesh -> Automatic, Axes -> True]
```

> ```
> same picture
> ```

Comment: I was hoping there was an easy build-in function for this. Is there ?

Comment: One could also use e.g. `LinearOptimization[x3, {x1 + 2 x2 - 2 x3 == 0 && -1 <= x1 <= 1 && -1 <= x2 <= 1}, {x1, x2, x3}]`

Comment: @ChrisDjango, try also `ImplicitRegion/ParametricRegion`

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**

@Chris Django

This equation $a x_1 + b x_2 + c x_3=0$ is in an **Orthogonal space** $\mathrm{R}^3$, so it is equivalent to $(a,b,c)\cdot (x_1,x_2,x_3)=0$,it means that $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ lies in the complement orthogonal space about the normal vector $(a,b,c)$,that is why we introduce the `HodgeDual` since all the $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ is belong to a linear space which span by the vectors of `HodgeDual`. If you want to affine space, the equation need to rewrite to depend on some bases such as $e_1,e_2,\cdots$,not the form $a x_1 + b x_2 + c x_3=0$

**Original**

It is easy to do this by `ParametricPlot3D` instead of `ContourPlot3D`

```
normal = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 3]
{v1, v2, v3} = HodgeDual[normal];
{e1, e2, e3} = Orthogonalize[{v1, v2, v3}];
ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0} + u*e1 + v*e2, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, Mesh -> None]
```

Comment: I was wondering how your answer encodes the algebraic linear equation in an affine space or did you tacitly invoke an inner product somewhere in your hodge and orthogonalize operations ?

Comment: @ChrisDjango Your equation is not in an affine space since all of them are use the  base {1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}. BTW, you want rectangle instead of Parallelogram,so here we use `Orthogonalize`

Comment: The base {1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1} can be the base of an affine space, as long as you don't define an inner product. So the space is affine. Pretty sure about that.

Comment: @ChrisDjango But Mathematica use build-in {1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1} and orthogonal space.in graphics such as `ContourPlot3D` or other graphics function.

Comment: This answer is not correct. You assume an inner product, instead of a mathematical paring. You could have also used the relativistic inner product. For examplen (a,b,c) \cdot_r (x1,x2, - x3) = a x1+ bx2 +c x 3, where (x1,x2,  x3) \cdot_r (x1,x2,  x3) = - x^2 + x2^2 + x^3. Your answer is not mathematically sound.

Comment: The base an affine expression, which happens to be displayed orthogonally in mathematica, which is one of infinitely many choices. The display requires an inner product but the expression itself is affine

Comment: @ChrisDjango  If you use `ContourPlot3D` to generate the above  graphics, all of the buil-in datas is in orthogonal space $\mathrm{R}^3$. Although you can interprete the plane as an affine space.

Comment: `normal = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 3];
{v1, v2, v3} = HodgeDual[normal];
ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0} + u*v1 + v*v2, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, Mesh -> None]` Compare with the two codes,here we didn't use orthographics.

Comment: So what would be your expression for the equation here ? I'm afraid you are using a normal vector, which uses perpendicularity and hence an inner product, which is not affine but metrical. Are you using a normal vector in your code?

Comment: If normal = {x,y,0} does not work

Comment: I really like this code. I use it as       `normal = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 3];
    {e1, e2, e3} = Orthogonalize@HodgeDual[normal];
    {e1, e2} = DeleteCases[{e1, e2, e3}, {0, 0, 0}, Infinity];
    ParametricPlot3D[{0, 0, 0} + u*e1 + v*e2, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, 
     BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, Mesh -> None]`